# Customizing Seam3 internationalization Messages

Tags: java, jsf-2, internationalization, seam, cdi

I am using Seam 3 Internationalization packages to implement messaging in my application.

In short, this is what I am doing:

Importing/Injecting required classes:

```
import org.jboss.seam.international.status.Messages;
import javax.inject.Inject;
@Inject
private Messages messages;
```

When an error occurs, I create a Message in my backing bean:

```
messages.error(new BundleKey("AppMsgResources", "errorMsgKey")).defaults("Error: Something bad happened!");
```

Lastly I display the message in my faces page like so:

```
<h:messages />
```

Very standard so far I think ...

The custom logic I want to implement is to be able to first check a database table (lets call this table MessageBundleOverride) for a matching message key. If it exists, I want to use the value from the MessageBundleOverride table and not the property file. If it doesnt exist or is empty, I want to use the value found in the property file.

I'm thinking there is a Weld/CDI way of doing this where I can implement the Messages interface and register it with seam somehow so that it picks up my messages implementation during "inject" and not the default MessagesImpl implementation that comes with Seam Internationalization package. I am a little new to Seam / Weld so not sure if this is a simple thing to do.

any help is much appreciated,
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out one way of getting this done after reading Weld docs: 
http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html#alternatives

```
@Alternative
@RequestScoped
public class MyMessages extends MessagesImpl {

/*
 * Override a method that you want to customize or write new code here
 */
@Override
public Set<Message> getAll() {
    Set<Message> allMessages = super.getAll();

    // do some custom logic here
    applyOverrides(allMessages);

    return allMessages;
}
...
// override any other method as needed 
// You will probably have to override everything so it probably 
// wouldnt make sense to extend the existing implementation)
...
}
```

In the beans.xml file, you will have to declare this new class as an alternative to the default:

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

    <alternatives>
        <class>com.company.project.view.messages.MyMessages</class>
    </alternatives>
</beans>
```

And that should do it so long as weld is picking up the classes in the package you have MyMessages defined in.